# Range of Years in JavaScript for a select box

Tags: javascript, arrays, range

I'm trying to create a dynamic select box in JavaScript with a range of years starting with 'some' year and ending with the current year. Is there anything like Ruby's [range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html) class in JavaScript or do I have to loop trough the years using a for loop?

Here's what I've come up with though I think it's a bit much considering in Ruby I can just use a range.

```
    this.years = function(startYear){
        startYear = (typeof(startYear) == 'undefined') ? 1980 : startYear
        var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
        var years = []
        for(var i=startYear;i<=currentYear;i++){
            years.push(i);
        } 
        return years;
    }
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

JavaScript does have a Range object, but it refers to an arbitrary portion of the DOM and is not supported in IE 6/7.

If you want, you can simplify your function to this, but it's all the same really.

```js
this.years = function(startYear) {
    var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear(), years = [];
    startYear = startYear || 1980;  
    while ( startYear <= currentYear ) {
        years.push(startYear++);
    }   
    return years;
}
 
console.log( this.years(2019-20));
```

Comment: Perfect. I didn't realize you could use the || operator instead of messing with typeof().

Comment: Ya, but only if false/null is an invalid value for whatever you're working on.  This is a very common method to provide a work around for default parameters.

Answer (score 35):

Use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Sequence_generator_(range))

```js
const currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
const range = (start, stop, step) => Array.from({ length: (stop - start) / step + 1}, (_, i) => start + (i * step));
console.log(range(currentYear, currentYear - 50, -1)); 
// [2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, ..., 1969]
```

Comment: Best answer here.

Comment: I don't really get what's happening here after the `length` part, the rest i understand... but it works. So, thanks. Could do with a bit of an explanation.

Comment: See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#sequence_generator_range

Answer (score 19):

This will generate an array starting in the current year and ending 50 years earlier.

```
Array.from({ length: 51 }, (_, i) => new Date().getFullYear() - i);
```

If you want to change the start year just adjust

```
new Date().getFullYear()
```

If you want to add from the start instead of subtracting just change the '-' into a '+'.

Comment: Simple and gets the job done.

Answer (score 12):

Use [Array.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) if you're transpiling or not worried about IE users.

```
const now = new Date().getUTCFullYear();    
const years = Array(now - (now - 20)).fill('').map((v, idx) => now - idx);

// (20) [2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000]
```

TypeScript

```
get years() {
  const now = new Date().getUTCFullYear();
  return Array(now - (now - 20)).fill('').map((v, idx) => now - idx) as Array<number>;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Thank you!

Comment: const years = Array(20)).fill('').map((v, idx) => now - idx);

Answer (score 8):

If you're looking for one line answer, you can use Array.from in one line to create a list of years.

```js
var years = Array.from(Array(new Date().getFullYear() - 1949), (_, i) => (i + 1950).toString())
console.log(years)
```

This will create years from 1950 to Current Year. This function will run in all browsers

Answer (score 6):

Use Date() and Array.from():

```
getCurrentYear = new Date().getFullYear(); // current year
listOfYears = Array.from({length: 11}, (_, i) => this.getCurrentYear - i);
console.log(listOfYears);
// Output: [2022, 2021, 2020, ...2012];
```

Answer (score 5):

This will generate an array starting in the current year and ending 10 years earlier.

```js
Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => new Date().getFullYear() - i);
// => [2022, 2021, 2020, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012]
```

Comment: Nice one liner :thumbs_up:

Answer (score 4):

While the above answers work perfectly I will just add an answer for [lodash](https://lodash.com/)
users.

> _.range([start=0], end, [step=1])

> Creates an array of numbers (positive and/or negative) progressing from start up to, but not including, end.

I added `1` to `max` since lodash doesn't include `end` in range.

This will create an array of year from 60 years ago to present.

You can use `_.rangeRight` if you want the opposite order.

```js
const max = new Date().getUTCFullYear();
const min = max - 60;
const yearRange = _.range(min, max + 1);

console.log(yearRange);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    getYear(){
       var currentYear = new Date().getFullYear(),
       var years = [];
       var startYear = 1980;
       for(var i=startYear; i<= currentYear; i++){
          year.push(startYear++);
       }
       return years;
    }
```

Comment: nothing is returned, and the rest is mostly in the question already

Comment: change `year. push` to `years.push`

Answer (score 3):

const years = [...Array(new Date().getFullYear() - 1989).keys()].map((e)=>e+1990)

This will generate year list from 1990 to current year
[1990,1991,.....2021]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, there's no "range" function in Javascript that's comparable to Ruby's, so you'll have to do it with a loop. It looks like what you're doing should work, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a range method in javascript, but you would need to use it a lot to pay for its inclusion in your source code.

`var A= Array.from(-5,5)` >>> return  value:

> (Array) -5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5

`var B= Array.from(10,100,10)` >>> return value:

> (Array) 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100

`var C= Array.from('a','z')` >>> return value:

> (Array)a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z

```
Array.from= function(what, n, step){
    var A= [];
    if(arguments.length){
        if(n){
            return A.range(what, n, step)
        }
        L= what.length;
        if(L){
            while(L){
                A[--L]= what[L];
            }
            return A;
        }
        if(what.hasOwnProperty){
            for(var p in what){
                if(what.hasOwnProperty(p)){
                    A[A.length]= what[p];
                }
            }
            return A;
        }
    }
    return A;
}

Array.prototype.range= function(what, n, step){
    this[this.length]= what;
    if(what.split && n.split){
        what= what.charCodeAt(0);
        n= n.charCodeAt(0);
        while(what<n){
            this[this.length]= String.fromCharCode(++what);
        }
    }
    else if(isFinite(what)){
        step= step || 1;
        while(what <n) this[this.length]= what+= step;
    }
    return this;
}
```