# set a year range in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, range

How can I define an array range without specifying each option in javascript?

Right now I have this:

```
    var year = { 
            '0': '2000',
                '1': '2001',
                '2': '2002',
                '3': '2003',
                '4': '2004',
                '5': '2005',
                '6': '2006',
                '7': '2007',
                '8': '2008',
                '9': '2009' 
            };
```

Comment: Um, you're missing a year

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575271/range-of-years-in-javascript-for-a-select-box

Comment: You are saying you want an array, but your code is using objects?

Answer (score 1):

You said you want an array, but you have a plain old object in your example. From your comment on this answer, however, it sounds like you really do want a normal object, so that's what I'll use.

At any rate, you can do this with a loop:

```
var year = {};        //or use [] if you want an array
var min_year = 2000;
var max_year = 2009;
for(var i = 0; i <= max_year - min_year; i++) {
    year[i] = i + min_year;
}

alert(year[5]);   //2005
```

You can expand on this example to suit your needs.

Comment: but using this I am getting year 3930 in my slider ( I have used {tag:'select','class':'span3', options: year } )

Comment: One thing to note here, that's not an array, the fact that you can do `year[5]` it's because your object literal has a 5 property

Comment: @NicoSantangelo correct. i used an object to emulate the OP's object. you could change my first line to `var year = [];` if you want a real array. (there's not much difference between arrays and normal objects in javascript anyway)

Comment: thanks @stano, yeah i guess that makes more sense. the most important thing here is that the OP realizes she can use a loop. i wasn't so worried about the rest, but being accurate is important too.

Comment: @stano updated - i totally missed that part of her comment, yeah generally you use a normal object when supplying options like that, so i think you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Your code example and your question are completely different:

1. This is considered to be an object

   ```
   var variable = {};
   ```
2. Whereas this is considered to be an array

   ```
   var variable = [];
   ```

There is a slight difference between them. For more information on the topic you can check 
[What is the difference between an array and an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874205/what-is-the-difference-between-an-array-and-an-object)

So, if you actually need an javascript array this code should do the work:

```
function generate_year_range(start, end){
    var years = [];
    for(var year = start; year <= end; year++){
        years.push(year)
    }
    return years;
}
var my_years = generate_year_range(2000,2009);
```

This will generate the years from 2000 to 2009(including) and store them into an array. So, your `my_years` variable will hold `[2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009]`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a loop to solve the issue

```
var startYr = 2000;

var year = function(i){
    return i + startYr;
};

// usage
year(0);

// output
2000
```

Comment: How exactly is this relative to the question? Your code will only return **one** year and would not store that into an array/object(hard to understand which one the user wants)