# from now (fullYear) to (fullYear) in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi guys is there any way in javascript that i can get the current full year and the next 5 years in the futue?

example:

```
new Date().getFullYear() and 'next 5 years in the future'

output:

[
  '2021',
  '2022',
  '2023',
  '2024',
  '2025',
  '2023'
]
```

Is there any way to do that?
Appreciate the help guys :)

Comment: seems like a simple loop...

Comment: Do you want to loop through all dates in the array, add 5 years then generate an array of the same length?

Comment: Add the values 1 through 5 to the current year?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575271/range-of-years-in-javascript-for-a-select-box/1575326

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create array of all integers between two numbers, inclusive, in Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069315/create-array-of-all-integers-between-two-numbers-inclusive-in-javascript-jquer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm overlooking something, this is a simple as using a loop to add the next 5 years to an array.

The following snippet shows a simple example of this using a `for` loop:

```js
let years = [];
let year = new Date().getFullYear();

for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  years.push(year++);
  
console.log(years);
```

This works by creating an empty array names `years`, and then storing the current year in `year`.  The `for` loop then adds each year from now to the next 5 years (`i < 6`) to the `years` array, incrementing `year` by one each time (`year++`).

Output:

```
[
  2021,
  2022,
  2023,
  2024,
  2025,
  2026
]
```

Comment: that's was exactly the method I was looking for thank you very much :)